# Prevent body from scrolling when modal open and jump to top

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I've been trying many solutions and I can't seem to make this work.

I've found a solution that works for preventing the body to scroll when the modal is open:

```
body.modal-open {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

This works fine. The problem is, when I open the modal the body scrolls to the top. I don't want this behaviour, and I understand it has to do with the position:fixed. I tried relative, and it did not work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which element triggers the modal? Can you share the code of this element?

Comment: have you tried using only overflow: hidden; and not with position: fixed;

Comment: Inacio: I have many modals, I am trying to make a fix to all of them. This CSS solution does fix the body scrolling issue for all of them, so I was looking for that kind of solution for jump to the top issue if possible

Comment: mulla.azzi yes, if I remove the position fixed the scrollbar will show up and allow scrolling on the body. The same is true for relative and absolute. It will solve the jump to top issue tho... I was looking for something that would solve both issues.

Comment: You could try reading the current scroll position before you open the modal and apply this class to body, and then re-set that same value afterwards. (Although not sure if that works in combination with limiting the body height to 100%.)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up figuring it out. What I did was removing the css I posted on the question, and then the following jquery adding a class to the html element, and in css styling that class:

JQUERY:

```
$(".modal").on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {

    $('html').addClass('no-scroll');

})
$(".modal").on('hide.bs.modal', function(event) {

    $('html').removeClass('no-scroll');

})
```

CSS:

```
.no-scroll{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using anchor(a) tag to open modal (or if you can rewrite your code to use it), then you can simply add `javascript:void` to prevent scroll to top. Example:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="open-modal-on-click">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you well, you can do something like this with Bootstrap:

```
// Avoid scrolling
body.modal-open, .modal-open .modal {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

And then add `.modal-dialog-centered` to `.modal-dialog` to vertically center the modal.

https://jsfiddle.net/4938ek6q/

Please, play resizing the result window in the example linked above to check if that's what you are looking for.

Hope this help or at least point you to the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this. Maybe it will be useful to you too. I removed "#" from modal buttom href attribute. Second step I added "cursor:pointer" to button css style. And end step I seted javascript onclik event my button id for modal open. Now very nice working.